# Unable to Edit Shapefiles - New Installation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation, tools, arcgis-10.6

I recently installed 10.6 and everything seems to be working great except I can not edit. It began every time I tried to edit a shapefile or feature class- the map would crash even with no basemaps or other data, so I added the editor toolbar and it seems to be "missing" something which explains why I am having this issue. [image]

Comment: It appears your install is incomplete/corrupt.  Try re-installing. If that fails, contact Tech Support.